# Java Date Format that allows - / or . as separators within date

Tags: java, simpledateformat, date-format, java-time, datetime-parsing

What's the nicest way to parse a date that can be in one of the following formats

```
 "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"
 "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"
 "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"
```

without creating 3 SimpleDateFormats and parsing against each one.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably easiest to "tweak" the source string into a canonical format:

```
if (text.length() == 16)
{
    if ((text.charAt(2) == '/' && text.charAt(5) == '/') ||
        (text.charAt(2) == '.' && text.charAt(5) == '.'))
    {
        text = text.substring(0, 2) + "-" + text.substring(3, 5) 
           + "-" + text.substring(6);
    }
}
```

Then use the format string using "-".

Note that this is very specific, only replacing *exactly* the characters you're interested in, to avoid unwanted side-effects.

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna start working on a generic date parser for our code base and this will be a good start

Answer (score 5):

Could you run two replace operations first, so that you reduce all three formats to a single one?

Comment: Ah.. i didnot see this one before posting my answer +1. great!

Answer (score 3):

You may use [Apache commons lang DateUtils.parseDate](http://commons.apache.org/lang//api/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateUtils.html#parseDate(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]))

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

    String[] values = new String[]{"31-12-2009 12:00", "31/12/2009 12:00", "31.12.2009 12:00"};
    String[] parsePatterns = new String[]{"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"};

    for (String value : values) {
        System.out.println(DateUtils.parseDate(value, parsePatterns));
    }
}
}
```

Well, internally it creates SimpleDateFormats, but whats wrong with that?

Answer (score 3):

## *java.time*

You can do it using [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) which allows you to specify optional things using square brackets.

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d[-][.][/]M[-][.][/]u H:m", Locale.ENGLISH);

        // Test
        Stream.of(
                    "28-04-2021 14:01", 
                    "28.04.2021 14:01", 
                    "28/04/2021 14:01"
        ).forEach(s -> System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse(s, dtf)));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-04-28T14:01
2021-04-28T14:01
2021-04-28T14:01
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Note that the legacy date-time API (`java.util` date-time types and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat`) are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> .

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

how about a regex:

```
"\\d\\d[./-]\\d\\d[./-]\\d\\d\\d\\d \\d\\d:\\d\\d"
```

In code this would mean something like this:

```
Pattern pattern = 
Pattern.compile("(\\d\\d)([./-])(\\d\\d)([./-])(\\d\\d\\d\\d) (\\d\\d):(\\d\\d)");

Matcher matcher = 
pattern.matcher("31-07-1983 15:30");

if (matcher.find() && matcher.group(2).equals(matcher.group(4))) {
  int day = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
  int month = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(3));
  int year = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(5));
  int hour = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(6));
  int minute = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(7));
}
```

Comment: Because \ is an escape character in Java string literals, you'd have to double each \: "\\d\\d[\\.\\/\\-]\\d\\d[\\.\\/\\-]\\d\\d\\d\\d \\d\\d:\\d\\d"

Comment: You are mistaken - you would still need to write "\\d" in your Java source code, regardless if this is a regular expression or not.

Comment: Now I had to go and check, you are absolutely right sir. That is ugly as hell, they could so easily just have used another escape character.

Answer (score 0):

Doing it yourself with a regular expression:

```
public class SpecialDateFormat
{
    private final static Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(\\d{2})[\\.\\/\\-](\\d{2})[\\.\\/\\-](\\d{4}) (\\d{2}):(\\d{2})");

    public static Date parse(String text) throws ParseException {
        Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(text);
        if (m.matches()) {
            int dd = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
            int mm = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));
            int yy = Integer.parseInt(m.group(3));
            int hh = Integer.parseInt(m.group(4));
            int mi = Integer.parseInt(m.group(5));

            // NOTE: Checking if values are in valid ranges omitted

            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.set(yy, mm - 1, dd, hh, mi, 0);

            return cal.getTime();
        }
        else {
            throw new ParseException("Unparseable date: " + text, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Note however that this does allow mixing different separators, e.g. "17-09/2009 12:00" would be allowed.

Comment: I call blatant stealing of concept ;-), you'll see that I've worked in the different separator checking with not much effort.

Comment: And apparently you do not need to escape any of the characters in between the [], not even the period.

Answer (score -3):

ParseExact can take an array of formats. You still have to specify all formats, but it's a single operation.

Comment: This is a Java question, there isn't a parseExact method

Comment: that's not a method of SimpleDateFormat, or the standard case for a Java method. Are you referencing C# or similar?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Yes, that's C#.